# A lightweight version of std::shared_ptr<T>

Tags: c++, memory-management, c++14, pointers

I wrote a simple lighter version of `std::shared_ptr<T>` called `res_ptr<T>`.

`std::shared_ptr<T>` is somewhat heavy due to all the nuances of its control block: support for safe deleting without virtual destructor, support for `std::weak_ptr<T>` (I am not certain on all details of the implementation... but I believe that it either requires an extra allocation for the control block, or has complicated logic on when to delete...).

The `res_ptr<T>` requires `T` to inherit from class `resource` that manages the reference counter and deletes the instance upon destruction once the counter reaches zero requires. Yes, it doesn't support array version `res_ptr<T[]>` and I don't think that it should but I might wrong.

`res_version<T>` is a helper class that attaches `resource` class to classes that do not inherit from `resource` that shouldn't change anything besides that.

Besides that, it is supposed to have fairly same interface as `std::shared_ptr<T>` and `std::unique_ptr<T>`. I know it currently lacks option for custom deleter but I don't think that I'll ever need it so I don't intend to implement it.

The implementation I have is written on Visual Studio and isn't fully portable. Though, honestly, this class is going to be the least of my worries once I need portability for the codebase. Though, if it is something else besides modifying `#pragma once` or issues with initialization of `std::atomic` I'd like to know.

I'd like to know if there are any issues or downsides that I failed to consider as well as general code review.

```
#pragma once
#include <atomic>

class resource
{
public:
    virtual ~resource()         = default;

    resource()                  = default;

    // moving / copying does not alter the reference counter
    resource(resource&&)                    noexcept : resource() {};
    resource(const resource&)               noexcept : resource() {};
    resource& operator = (resource&&)       noexcept {};
    resource& operator = (const resource&)  noexcept {};

    void    add_ref()               const   noexcept
    {
        m_refcount.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }

    int     reduce_ref()            const   noexcept
    {
        return m_refcount.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_relaxed)-1;
    }

    int     count()                 const   noexcept
    {
        return m_refcount.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    }

private:
    mutable std::atomic<int>    m_refcount = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class res_version :
    public T, public resource
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    res_version(Args... args):
        T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
    {};
};

template<typename PResource, typename Enable = void>
class res_ptr;

template<typename PResource>
class res_ptr<PResource, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<resource, PResource>>>
{
public:
    template<typename PResourceDerived, typename E>
    friend class res_ptr;

    constexpr   res_ptr()           noexcept = default;
    constexpr   res_ptr(nullptr_t)  noexcept {};

    template<typename PResourceDerived, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<PResource, PResourceDerived>, int> = 0>
    explicit    res_ptr(PResourceDerived* ptr) : m_ptr(static_cast<PResource*>(ptr))
    {
        if(m_ptr) m_ptr->add_ref();
    };

    ~res_ptr()
    {
        release();
    }

    // copy ctor
    res_ptr(const   res_ptr& ptr) noexcept :
        m_ptr(ptr.get())
    {
        if (m_ptr) m_ptr->add_ref();
    };

    // copy ctor cast
    template<typename PResourceDerived, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<PResource, PResourceDerived> && !std::is_same_v<PResource, PResourceDerived>,int> = 0>
    res_ptr(            const   res_ptr<PResourceDerived> & ptr) noexcept :
        m_ptr(static_cast<PResource*>(ptr.get()))
    {
        if (m_ptr) m_ptr->add_ref();
    };

    // move ctor
    res_ptr(                    res_ptr&& ptr) noexcept :
        m_ptr(std::exchange(ptr.m_ptr, nullptr))
    {};

    // move ctor cast
    template<typename PResourceDerived, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<PResource, PResourceDerived> && !std::is_same_v<PResource, PResourceDerived>,int> = 0>
    res_ptr(                    res_ptr<PResourceDerived> &&    ptr) noexcept :
        m_ptr(static_cast<PResource*>(std::exchange(ptr.m_ptr, nullptr)))
    {};

    // copy
    res_ptr& operator = (const  res_ptr&        other) noexcept
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            release();
            m_ptr = other.m_ptr;

            if (m_ptr) m_ptr->add_ref();
        }

        return *this;
    }

    // move
    res_ptr& operator = (       res_ptr&&       other) noexcept
    {
        if (this != &other)
        {
            release();
            m_ptr = std::exchange(other.m_ptr,nullptr);
        }

        return *this;
    }

    // copy cast
    template<typename PResourceDerived, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<PResource, PResourceDerived> && !std::is_same_v<PResource, PResourceDerived>, int> = 0>
    res_ptr& operator = (const  res_ptr<PResourceDerived>&      other) noexcept
    {
        release();
        m_ptr = static_cast<PResource*>(other.m_ptr);

        if (m_ptr) m_ptr->add_ref();

        return *this;
    }

    // move cast
    template<typename PResourceDerived, std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<PResource, PResourceDerived> && !std::is_same_v<PResource, PResourceDerived>, int> = 0>
    res_ptr& operator = (       res_ptr<PResourceDerived>&& other) noexcept
    {
        release();
        m_ptr = static_cast<PResource*>(std::exchange(other.m_ptr,nullptr));

        return *this;
    }

    PResource* operator ->  ()  const noexcept
    {
        return m_ptr;
    }
    PResource& operator *   ()  const noexcept
    {
        return *m_ptr;
    }
    PResource* get()            const noexcept
    {
        return m_ptr;
    }
    operator bool   ()          const noexcept
    {
        return m_ptr != nullptr;
    }

    void release()
    {
        if (m_ptr && (m_ptr->reduce_ref() == 0))
        {
            delete m_ptr;
        }
    }

    template<typename PResource>
    bool operator == (const res_ptr<PResource>& other) noexcept
    {
        return m_ptr == other.m_ptr;
    }

    template<typename PResource>
    bool operator != (const res_ptr<PResource>& other) noexcept
    {
        return m_ptr != other.m_ptr;
    }

private:
    PResource* m_ptr = nullptr;
};

template<typename PResource, typename... Args>
res_ptr<PResource>          make_resource(Args&& ... args)
{
    return res_ptr<PResource>(new PResource(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

template<typename PResourceDerived, typename PResourceBase>
res_ptr<PResourceDerived>   resource_dynamic_cast(const res_ptr<PResourceBase>& uPtr) noexcept
{
    PResourceDerived* ptr = dynamic_cast<PResourceDerived*>(uPtr.get());

    return res_ptr<PResourceDerived>(ptr);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any tests?  It's worth including them in the review (for two reasons: it helps reviewers run and exercise the code themselves, and it may identify corner cases that need testing).

Comment: There is a reason that `std::shared_ptr` is not light wait. Its difficult to write correctly and needs all that code.

Comment: @MartinYork `res_ptr<T>` is not designed to replace `std::shared_ptr<T>` but to provide a more efficient version for certain classes.

Comment: @TobySpeight I don't have any tests dedicated to `res_ptr<T>`... only tests that utilize `res_ptr<T>` within larger projects. If you can supplement some good ideas on those edge cases that are worth testing you can post it as an answer.

Comment: @ALX23z not sure I am convinced this is any more efficient than `std::shared_ptr` (having read the code) you would need to show me evidence of that. Also since `std::shared_ptr` has much more testing on it I am inclined to think there is something non obvious here that will cause problems (without lots of though going into testing and validating). They found bugs in shared_ptr for well over a decade after it was first written before it got to its current state. It is a good try (probably one of the best I have seen) but this should not be used in production code.

Comment: @MartinYork currently it is for development code. I do believe there might be issues when this class is used in odd cases. I didn't bother dealing with `const / volatile` and I am not entirely sure how to address them with smart pointers since my skills with SFINAE are limited - I heard that even for `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` this doesn't work perfectly due to language limitations. For general use, the biggest problem is the design itself as it requires the underlying class to inherit from `resource`. How does one properly inherits from `resource`? Each version has issues.

Comment: @MartinYork The **number one issue (to me)** with shared_ptr (and most std template types) is the cost of the template instantiation: it does not scale as the number of templates in the application grows. It tries to do 'many things', when in most cases the 'many things' don't apply; if they do, use it. However, shared_ptr is *against* "pay only for what you use". (That said, there are already several such lightweight implementations in-the-wild too.)

Comment: @user2864740 What you said does not make any sense. Templates only instantiate what they need (never more), the cost is never more than the cost of creating the class. So the statement **it does not scale** is just ludicrously wrong. The statement  **'many things'** is also misguided and totally untrue. The use of SFINE is the classic example of how that is not true (each type is specifically instantiated with only what needs to be done and specialized). Also **pay only for what you use** I see as totally misleading as you only pay for waht you use (as with all templates). Prove your statement

Comment: @user2864740 **That said, there are already several such lightweight implementations in-the-wild too**. Sure there are always people that want to try their hand for lots of reasons. This does not mean it is a good idea. Please provide data that any of these "light-weight" ones are better than `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Perhaps you missed the part about “compilation”. It does not scale with the number of distinct instantiations due to having a very high C cost per-instantiation type. This is easy to verify using Clang and “-ftime-trace”, or measuring compilation times with an increasing number of T-types. Hint: the cost in Clang on our code is over 100ms PER type instantiation. Maybe some compilers are much better *shrug*. Hence, it does not scale (or scales linearly at an impractical rate). Compare to unique_ptr which is barely 1ms, or a custom lightweight implementation that is equally as fast per T-inst.

Comment: Coupled with template issues in general (ie. needing instantiations in each TU for open types) this can easily lead to per-TU costs which further exasperates the scaling issue into slow program compilation times.

Comment: What's the justification for the use of `memory_order_relaxed`?

Comment: @curiousguy there isn't. Just nobody commented that it is wrong. It should be `release` on reducing count, and additional `acquire` prior to delete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Missing headers

- `<cstddef>` for `std::nullptr_t`
- `<type_traits>` for `std::is_base_of_v`, `std::is_same_v`, `std::enable_if_t`
- `<utility>` for `std::exchange`, `std::forward`

## Layout

The code is hard to read, with long lines and huge blocks of spaces (perhaps a misguided attempt to align keywords?).  Stick to a conventional layout and it will be much easier to read.

## Fix the errors and warnings

These should need no further explanation (except perhaps the one caused by misspelling `std::nullptr_t`):

```
231599.cpp: In member function ‘resource& resource::operator=(resource&&)’:
231599.cpp:13:55: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
   13 |     resource& operator = (resource&&)       noexcept {};
      |                                                       ^
      |                                                       return *this;
231599.cpp: In member function ‘resource& resource::operator=(const resource&)’:
231599.cpp:14:55: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
   14 |     resource& operator = (const resource&)  noexcept {};
      |                                                       ^
      |                                                       return *this;
231599.cpp: At global scope:
231599.cpp:43:7: warning: extra ‘;’ [-Wpedantic]
   43 |     {};
      |       ^
      |       -
231599.cpp:57:5: error: non-static data member ‘nullptr_t’ declared ‘constexpr’
   57 |     constexpr   res_ptr(nullptr_t)  noexcept {};
      |     ^~~~~~~~~
231599.cpp:57:34: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
   57 |     constexpr   res_ptr(nullptr_t)  noexcept {};
      |                                  ^
      |                                   ;
231599.cpp:57:37: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘noexcept’
   57 |     constexpr   res_ptr(nullptr_t)  noexcept {};
      |                                     ^~~~~~~~
231599.cpp:63:6: warning: extra ‘;’ [-Wpedantic]
   63 |     };
      |      ^
      |      -
231599.cpp:83:6: warning: extra ‘;’ [-Wpedantic]
   83 |     };
      |      ^
      |      -
231599.cpp:94:7: warning: extra ‘;’ [-Wpedantic]
   94 |     {};
      |       ^
      |       -
231599.cpp:169:14: error: declaration of template parameter ‘PResource’ shadows template parameter
  169 |     template<typename PResource>
      |              ^~~~~~~~
231599.cpp:49:10: note: template parameter ‘PResource’ declared here
   49 | template<typename PResource>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
231599.cpp:175:14: error: declaration of template parameter ‘PResource’ shadows template parameter
  175 |     template<typename PResource>
      |              ^~~~~~~~
231599.cpp:49:10: note: template parameter ‘PResource’ declared here
   49 | template<typename PResource>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
231599.cpp: In constructor ‘res_ptr<PResource, typename std::enable_if<is_base_of_v<resource, PResource>, void>::type>::res_ptr(res_ptr<PResource, typename std::enable_if<is_base_of_v<resource, PResource>, void>::type>&&)’:
231599.cpp:87:20: error: ‘exchange’ is not a member of ‘std’
   87 |         m_ptr(std::exchange(ptr.m_ptr, nullptr))
      |                    ^~~~~~~~
231599.cpp: In constructor ‘res_ptr<PResource, typename std::enable_if<is_base_of_v<resource, PResource>, void>::type>::res_ptr(res_ptr<PResourceDerived>&&)’:
231599.cpp:93:44: error: ‘exchange’ is not a member of ‘std’
   93 |         m_ptr(static_cast<PResource*>(std::exchange(ptr.m_ptr, nullptr)))
      |                                            ^~~~~~~~
231599.cpp: In member function ‘res_ptr<PResource, typename std::enable_if<is_base_of_v<resource, PResource>, void>::type>& res_ptr<PResource, typename std::enable_if<is_base_of_v<resource, PResource>, void>::type>::operator=(res_ptr<PResource, typename std::enable_if<is_base_of_v<resource, PResource>, void>::type>&&)’:
231599.cpp:116:26: error: ‘exchange’ is not a member of ‘std’
  116 |             m_ptr = std::exchange(other.m_ptr,nullptr);
      |                          ^~~~~~~~
231599.cpp: In member function ‘res_ptr<PResource, typename std::enable_if<is_base_of_v<resource, PResource>, void>::type>& res_ptr<PResource, typename std::enable_if<is_base_of_v<resource, PResource>, void>::type>::operator=(res_ptr<PResourceDerived>&&)’:
231599.cpp:139:46: error: ‘exchange’ is not a member of ‘std’
  139 |         m_ptr = static_cast<PResource*>(std::exchange(other.m_ptr,nullptr));
      |                                              ^~~~~~~~
231599.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
231599.cpp:207:34: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class res_ptr<int, void>’
  207 |     auto a = make_resource<int>(5);
      |                                  ^
231599.cpp:47:7: note: declaration of ‘class res_ptr<int, void>’
   47 | class res_ptr;
      |       ^~~~~~~
231599.cpp: In instantiation of ‘res_ptr<PResource> make_resource(Args&& ...) [with PResource = int; Args = {int}]’:
231599.cpp:207:34:   required from here
231599.cpp:186:29: error: return type ‘class res_ptr<int, void>’ is incomplete
  186 | res_ptr<PResource>          make_resource(Args&& ... args)
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
231599.cpp:188:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class res_ptr<int, void>’
  188 |     return res_ptr<PResource>(new PResource(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
231599.cpp:47:7: note: declaration of ‘class res_ptr<int, void>’
   47 | class res_ptr;
      |       ^~~~~~~
```

## Usage guidance

My first simple test, expecting a similar interface to `std::make_shared()`, failed:

```
auto a = make_resource<int>(5);
```

So I tried the next most obvious course:

```
auto a = make_resource<res_version<int>>(5);
```

This also fails, due to attempting to inherit from a non-struct type.

It seems I need to create a struct (with a constructor) even for something this simple!  Much less friendly than the standard shared pointer.

## Questionable choices

Why use `int` to count references?  An unsigned type would be more appropriate.

We should check for overflow before incrementing the counter, and throw an exception if that would happen, otherwise we could delete objects still in use.  I don't think that's possible without changing away from `std::memory_order_relaxed`.

The `res_version` adapter should virtually inherit `resource`, to avoid the diamond problem when subclasses inherit from more than one of these.

I'd prefer the `res_version` constructor to include an initializer for the `resource` base, rather than omitting it.  The `T()` constructor is likely to be tricky here, as it makes it hard for users to select the `T{}` constructor - important for classes such as `std::vector`.

The statement `if (m_ptr) m_ptr->add_ref();` is used many times - worth encapsulating in a member function (any decent compiler will inline it).

`std::is_base_of_v<PResource, PResourceDerived> && !std::is_same_v<PResource, PResourceDerived>` is used many times - encapsulate that too (`is_derived_from<>`, perhaps?).

<del>We haven't implemented `swap()`, so `std::swap()` will fall back to copying via a temporary, which implies needless updates to the count.</del>

`res_ptr::operator=(res_ptr&&)` can be implemented in terms of `swap()` (if we write that), instead of releasing first.

Comment: I find standard layout unreadable. Fixed errors with copy and move assignment for `resource` (strange that MSVS doesn't care...). I never tried to work with base types... nor it was designed to do so. It is annoying that C++ works this way. About why `int` to count references... I doubt it will ever make int overflow `int` for ref counter so it is not a practical error. `is_derived_from<>` perhaps the encapsulation is preferred indeed, but I am not too certain how to properly address cases when keywords `const/volatile` are included.

Comment: "The res_version adapter should virtually inherit resource, to avoid the diamond problem when subclasses inherit from more than one of these." I don't think so. If a subclass inherits `resource` version then you shouldn't make `res_version` to begin with; or better make a compatibility version that doesn't add anything anything if `resource` is a subclass.

Comment: Wait... doesn't `swap` use `std::move` when possible? If it doesn't then it is a `std` error or the compiler's implementation of `std` fault.

Comment: Ah yes, `std::swap()` requires `MoveAssignable`, so that's okay after all.

Comment: `int` may overflow with as little as 32768 references, depending on the platform.  You might consider that "unlikely", but I'd probably go for a `std::size_t` if not checking for overflow.

Comment: I see `int` overflow is a portability issue. I am too used with `int` being 4 bytes long. Will switch to `std::size_t` or `unsigned long`... BTW are there any promises that `std::size_t` or `unsigned long` can be atomic without utilization of mutexes?

Comment: No, just as there isn't such a guarantee for `std::atomic<int>` - it's entirely dependent on the capabilities of the target you're compiling for, so the C++ standard can't mandate such choices.  It's what you'd call a quality of implementation issue.  I'd expect most platforms to use spinlocks rather than process mutexes if they don't have hardware atomic integer operations, though.

Comment: Checking for overflow and throwing is a trade-off more so than a preferable choice. Particularly so when the emphasis is lightweight.

Comment: @PasserBy, true - but let's make sure it's a *conscious* trade-off!

Answer (score 4):

The only thing I see that is a mistake is the bool operator. Instead of:

```
operator bool   ()          const noexcept
```

You probably want:

```
explicit operator bool   ()          const noexcept
```

The `explicit` prevents the compiler from being able to automatically convert  your object to `bool` as part of a comparison.

```
res_ptr<X>     data = getResPtr();

if (true == data) {
    // Not sue you want that auto conversion.
    // The standard shared_ptr does not want this implicit conversion
    // I am sure there are other cases where it can be out-converted where
    // you don't want that to happen.

         doSomeWorkWithBool(data); // If that function takes a bool
                                   // it auto converts before the call.
                                   // auto conversions are not usually what
                                   // you want.
}

// Note:
if (data) {
    // This still works as expected with the explicit
    // It is designed so that in a bool context like if()/while()/for() etc
    // the explicit conversion to bool is applied but in other contexts it
    // does not work any you need an explicit cast

    doSomeWorkWithBool(static_cast<bool>(data)); // Need an explict cast here
                                                 // if you use the `explicit`
                                                 // in the bool operator.
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I added `explicit` in the code (I don't update the question's version as per rules). Though, what you posted raised a question for me... `res_ptr<int>` does not compile because `int` doesn't inherit from resource. `res_ptr<res_version<int>>` needs to be used for this class to work with `int`. I didn't design `res_ptr` class to work with `int` so it might not be an issue but this design might be an issue in itself...